# Return a std::function with auto return type

Tags: c++, types, return, auto, std-function

I want to create a functor to convert a std::string to different types.

```
std::function<auto(const std::string)> create(const std::string &type)
{
  if(type=="int") {
    return [&](const std::string &value){return std::stoi(value);}
  } else if(type=="float") {
    return [&](const std::string &value){return std::stof(value);}
  }  else {
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  }
}
```

But it seems like we cannot use **auto** as a return type of **std::function** here.

Can someone suggest a way to do this please?

Comment: You could use [`std::variant<int, float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Are you open to using templates and template specialization?

Comment: I have some data of different types as strings. So need to cast them. I can use templates

Answer (score 4):

The return type must be the same and fixed for one function or one instantiation of function template. You can make the function template as

```
template <typename R>
std::function<R(const std::string&)> create()
{
  if(std::is_same<R, int>::value) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stoi(value);};
  } else if(std::is_same<R, float>::value) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stof(value);};
  }  else {
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  }
}
```

then use it like

```
auto f_int = create<int>();
auto f_float = create<float>();
```

Since C++17 you can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), the unnecessary statement would be discarded at compile-time.

```
template <typename R>
std::function<R(const std::string&)> create()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, int>) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stoi(value);};
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, float>) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stof(value);};
  }  else {
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  }
}
```

BTW: As the return type the parameter of the `std::function` should be `const std::string&`. And the lambda seems no need to capture anything.

BTW2: Depending on how you use the return value, returning the lambda directly instead of wrapping it into `std::function` might be sufficient too.

```
template <typename R>
auto create()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, int>) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stoi(value);};
  } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, float>) {
    return [](const std::string &value){return std::stof(value);};
  }  else {
    throw std::runtime_error("");
  }
}
```

Comment: The parameter is obsolete now

Comment: This will not do. The type information and value both I have is actually in string format. So I have to check the type string first to make the appropriate cast functor and then use it to cast the value string to appropriate type

Comment: @shaaa So you want the return type changing at runtime based on the content of the string. Then you have to use sth like `std::variant` or `std::any` as @SimonKraemer commented. And you have to know the exact type even when the function returns, otherwise you can't get the value from them.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is possible to have auto return type deduction in a `std::function`.

If you need to store a lambda/functor that calls the `std::sto*` function, I've come up with some alternatives. Simply make create a template itself and replace `auto` with it. This allows you to remove the `const std::string&` type parameter.

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::is_same

template <typename T = int>
constexpr std::function<T(const std::string)> create()
{
    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)   
    { return [&](const std::string &value) { return std::stoi(value); }; }

    if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) 
    { return [&](const std::string &value) { return std::stof(value); }; }

    throw std::runtime_error("");
}
```

Or you could create a functor class yourself.

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::is_same

template <typename T = int>
struct Functor {

    T operator()(const std::string& input) {
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)   { return std::stoi(input); };
        if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) { return std::stof(input); };
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }

};
```

Usage for the above.

```
int main() {
    
    auto f_i = create();
    auto f_f = create<float>();
    f_i("42");   // returns an int
    f_f("3.14"); // returns a float
    
    Functor fo_i;
    Functor<float> fo_f;
    fo_i("42");   // returns an int
    fo_f("3.14"); // returns a float
    
}
```

I would suggest that simply calling the correct numeric conversion function instead of storing a lambda/functor that calls `std::sto*` would be a better approach.